# Static weaving not working eclipse link and Jboss

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, jpa, eclipselink

I am trying to do static weaving with eclipse link and Jboss.

I have configured the static weaving in persistence.xml file.

```
      <property name="eclipselink.weaving" value="static"/>
```

I use eclipse link 2.4 so used the maven plugin.

```
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>eclipselink-staticweave-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <groupId>au.com.alderaan</groupId>
                <version>1.0.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>weave</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>process-classes</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <logLevel>ALL</logLevel>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>

                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
                        <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
                        <version>2.4.0</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>

            </plugin>
        </plugins>
</build>
```

When the build happens it is weaving all classes successfully, but when server starts up it is showing it is reverting the lazy loading as weaving is not enabled or did not occur.

I am not seeing any issue, I check the Jar size after weaving it has increase almost double and the same in included in ear file. I am not understanding why the weaving will not occur.

The message I am getting during server startup is
The message I am getting is 10:58:00,566

```
INFO  [STDOUT] [EL Warning]: 2015-01-07 10:58:00.566--    ServerSession(2048717004)--Thread(Thread[main,5,jboss])--Reverting the lazy setting on the OneToOne or ManyToOne attribute [MyClass] for the entity class [class com.test.EntityClass] since weaving was not enabled or did not occur.
```

I tried decompiling the class and could see the following imports added, which I believe the weaving is done.

```
import org.eclipse.persistence.indirection.WeavedAttributeValueHolderInterface;
import org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.PersistenceEntity;
import org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.PersistenceObject;
import org.eclipse.persistence.internal.identitymaps.CacheKey;
import org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl;
import org.eclipse.persistence.internal.weaving.PersistenceWeaved;
import org.eclipse.persistence.internal.weaving.PersistenceWeavedChangeTracking;
import org.eclipse.persistence.internal.weaving.PersistenceWeavedFetchGroups;
import org.eclipse.persistence.internal.weaving.PersistenceWeavedLazy;
import org.eclipse.persistence.internal.weaving.PersistenceWeavedRest;
```

I am using
Jboss5.1-eap
eclipselink2.4, spring 3.2 and Jdk 1.6

I was reading the documentation for Spring

Any thoughts.

Comment: Can you show the message?  If the jar contains the enhanced classes, it should not need to be woven again at runtime for lazy relationships and other performance enhancements to be used - they should already be in the class files directly and just get used by EclipseLink.  How have you configured your persistence.xml?

Comment: Yes I have configured it. <property name="eclipselink.weaving" value="static"/> in my persistence.xml, I was reading the documentation for spring  https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Spring it is saying Spring's agent does not initialize the persistence context until the application accesses the Spring context. If the application has already triggered the loading of the persistent class before accessing the Spring context, weaving will not occur. Do you think it may be the issue.

Comment: The message I am getting is 10:58:00,566 INFO  [STDOUT] [EL Warning]: 2015-01-07 10:58:00.566--ServerSession(2048717004)--Thread(Thread[main,5,jboss])--Reverting the lazy setting on the OneToOne or ManyToOne attribute [MyClass] for the entity class [class com.test.EntityClass] since weaving was not enabled or did not occur.

Comment: Accessing classes outside the Persistence unit only matters with dynamic weaving - If you have statically woven classes, it should not matter when the persistence unit is accessed, since the changes exist in the classfiles directly.  It seems you might have included the unwoven class files on your classpath somehow, and the unwoven classes are being picked up first.  Can you check the package and decompile your entities to see if they implenent EclipseLink constructs?  And check that there is only 1 version of each entity class on the classpath for your application.

Comment: I could see below imports to the class file, I am adding it to the main message.